# What is the idiomatic way to route a non model param in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that I'd like to filter the store with but it's using a property that isn't on the model itself

```
App.Appointment = DS.Model.extend({                                                      
    details: attr('string')                                         
});

App.Router.map(function(match) {                                               
    this.resource("appointments", { path: "/appointments" }, function() {      
        this.route("index", { path: "/:day/all" });                
    });                                                                        
});
```

When I hit the model method for this route, I simply query the api using this "day" property (as it's a legit way to query the backend). But because it's not part of the model I don't believe this is the way ember "should" work.

```
App.AppointmentsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('appointment', params);
    }
});
```

How should I write the route for an ember model that doesn't expose a model property like this?

I should also mention that this doesn't work well when the setupController method is invoked because the "model" param that's injected is {day: "2013-01-01"} instead of an array of appointment models (I can hack around this but it feels like I'm doing it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a hash object solved this problem (so until query params are supported this is a good solution that feels less hacky)

```
App.AppointmentsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      appointments: this.store.find('appointment', params),
      day: params.day
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.get('appointments'));
    controller.set('day', model.get('day'));
  }
});
```

I should also show that if you create a linkTo helper or transition to this route you need to do it like so

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({                                          
    redirect: function() {                                                     
        var now = new Date();                                                  
        var today = moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD');                          
        this.transitionTo('appointments.index', today);                        
    }                                                                          
});
```